# Nautilus' Properties tab does not show full path of the file if the path is too long

Tags: nautilus, gui, filemanager, paths

Whenever a file's path is too long, Nautilus doesn't display the path in full and instead chooses to use ... to replace the last parts of the path. This is annoying and very unhelpful because often it's the case that I want to locate a file at its exact location after a search.

[image: Example]

Surprisingly I've never seen this problem anywhere. A Google search led me to the [only bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/141292) which was closed for being a "duplicate" though the supposed duplicate issue is nowhere to be found.

Is there a way to let Nautilus always display the full path of a file?

Comment: Stretching the window shows the whole path (14.04)

Comment: Also fancy options are possible, automatically setting (changing) the window size,  but it would get a bit like patchwork. Nice and interesting, but unclean. *Copying* the entry (Ctrl+A / Ctrl+C) *does* copy the full path by the way.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I see. I think a more reasonable thing to do instead of letting the user stretch the window is to just display the path in multiple lines. But that seems to be the temporary solution then.

Comment: Is your main goal to copy the full path or to see it?

Comment: @JacobVlijm See it, I think. I'd like to differentiate between files via the exact location they're in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not literally the answer you asked for, yet a solution to the issue.....

#### Alternative way to quickly view the full path to a file or folder by right-click

[image]

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os

current = os.getenv(
    "NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI"
    ).replace("file://", "").replace("%20", " ").strip()
subprocess.Popen([
    "zenity", "--info", "--title=Path info", '--text='+current, "--no-wrap"
    ])
```

#### How to use

- save the tiny script below into an empty file, save it as `show_path` (no extension) in `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`
- Make it executable (!)
- Log out and back in

Now you'll have a right- click option to always see the full path to a file or directory, ready to see or copy:

right-click > Scripts > show_path

[image]

Comment: But what if the path is so long that it does not fit _this_ window?! I can see you have even walked yourself into the trap of adding the `--no-wrap` option! Bwahahahhha! Makes me want to take back my upvote!!4!!! `/s`